# Getting center location of square when mouse is clicked? Java

Tags: java, arrays, graphics, paint

This is a bit more of a conceptual question.  Lets say you have an array of squares, each 40 pixels by 40 pixels. Lets also say you clicked inside one of them. How would you get another object to appear in the center of the box that was clicked instead of where exactly the mouse was clicked?
Would you use an offset of some kind? I am really struggling to understand how to determine the center of the square in relation to the mouse clicked.

Comment: What measurements do you have for each square?  The co-ordinates of the upper left corner, plus the side length?  Or the co-ordinates of two diagonally opposite corners?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your could calculate the position of the box which was clicked (`mousex / 40` for column and `mousey / 40` for row), then you would simply need to calculate the center position for the object...

Normally something like...

```
int x = (parentWidth - childWidth) / 2;
int y = (parentWidth - childWidth) / 2;
```

would give you the center position for the child within the parent.  You would then simply apply the offset of the box in question...

```
int x = xOffset + ((parentWidth - childWidth) / 2);
int y = yOffset + ((parentWidth - childWidth) / 2);
```